# How do I improve the run time to receive the training samples?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have the following problems the following code snippet is correct only this one is slow. For example, I need 10 minutes to go through this. However, I don't know how to speed it up. Does somebody has any idea?

```
#Dataframe:

 list_l = [[0, 3, 8, 0], [0, 8, 7, 0], [0, 2, 9, 0], [1, 10, 10, 1], [2, 3, 8, 2], [2, 10, 10, 2], [3, 4, 12, 3], [3, 12, 4, 3], [3, 3, 8, 3], [4, 12, 4, 4], [4, 3, 8, 4], [4, 4, 12, 4], [5, 8, 7, 5], [5, 6, 13, 5], [5, 3, 8, 5], [6, 0, 3, 6], [6, 5, 11, 6], [6, 12, 4, 6], [7, 9, 6, 7], [7, 9, 6, 7], [8, 13, 5, 8], [9, 1, 0, 9], [9, 7, 2, 9], [9, 11, 1, 9], [9, 11, 1, 9]]
 # Note: location isn't relevant
 df = DataFrame (list_l ,columns=['buyerid','itemid', 'group', 'location'])

 #train_mat:

# trainmat
# How have to generate train_mat by yourself
# df_main =  complete dataframe, data = splitted dataframe (complete dataframe is also ok)
def generate_matrix(df_main,data):
  num_users = df_main["buyerid"].nunique()
  num_items = df_main["itemid"].nunique()
  print(num_users)
  print(num_items)
  mat = sp.dok_matrix((num_users, num_items), dtype=np.float32)
  for buyerid, itemidin zip(data['buyerid'], data['itemid']):
    mat[buyerid, itemid] = 1.0
  print(mat)
  return mat
  #num_negatives:

# num_negatives = 4
```

Code:

```
# allData = complete Dataframe, train_mat = one hot encoding matrix, num_negatives = integer
def get_train_samples(allData, train_mat, num_negatives):
    user_input, item_input, labels = [], [], []
    num_user, num_item = train_mat.shape
    for (u, i) in train_mat.keys():
        user_input.append(u)
        item_input.append(i)
        labels.append(1)
        # negative instances
        for t in range(num_negatives):
            j = np.random.randint(num_item)
            if allData.loc[(allData['buyerid'] == u)&(allData['itemid'] == i)].empty:
                j = np.random.randint(num_item)
            user_input.append(u)
            item_input.append(j)
            labels.append(0)
    return user_input, item_input, labels
```

Comment: it's better to not call something just 'list', as that overwrites the built-in list() function, and you may need that later (even if you don't need it later it's just good practice to avoid name collisions where possible)

Answer (score 0):

some things to improve here:

```
for t in range(num_negatives):
    j = np.random.randint(num_item)
    if allData.loc[(allData['buyerid'] == u)&(allData['itemid'] == i)].empty:
        j = np.random.randint(num_item)
```

you essentially say "j is a random number, if some stuff is true, set j to a random number". Isn't that just "j is a random number" with extra steps?

I'd say this does the same but faster

```
for t in range(num_negatives):
    j = np.random.randint(num_item)
```

edit: removing brain fart